# Выводится название, а не значение переменной

Tags: python

Нужно сравнить два числа и перед этим должно написано "Введите два натуральных числа". Когда проверяю выводит название, а не значения переменных

```
a=int(input("Введите два натуральных числа"))

b=int(input("Введите два натуральных числа"))

if a<b:
    print ("Наибольшее число: b ")
    print("Наименьшее число: a ")
else:
    print("Наибольшее число: a ")
    print ("Наименьшее число: b ")
```

Comment: Ну используйте f-строки: `print(f"Наибольшее число: {b}")` и т.д.

Comment: `print("Наименьшее число: ",a )`

Comment: `print(f"Наибольшее число: {max(a, b)}\nНаименьшее число: {min(a, b)}")`

Comment: Выводится не название переменной, а текст в кавычках.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка в следующем:

> print ("Наибольшее число: b ")

То, что находится внутри кавычек является строкой.
"b" в данном случае - просто символ, который не "заменяется" значением переменной при обработке кода интерпретатором.

Помочь вам могут f-строки. Суть которых в возможности внести в строку блоки, которые будут восприниматься интерпретатором как выражения.

Пример использования f-строки:

```
a = 2
print(f"Значение переменной а = {a}")
```

Вывод будет таким >>> Значение переменной а = 2

Полный пример решения с использованием f-строк такой:

```
a=int(input("Введите два натуральных числа:\n"))
b=int(input())
if a > b:
    print(f"Наибольшее число a = {a}")
elif b > a:
    print(f"Наибольшее число b = {b}")
else:
    print(f"Оба числа равны {b}")
```

Еще один способ - воспользоваться возможностями **print()**.
print может принимать множество аргументов разных типов.
Например:

```
a = 2
b = "two"
print("Текст", a, "еще текст", b)
```

В результате вывод >>> Текст 2 еще текст two

Пример решения через аргументы print:

```
a = int(input("Введите два натуральных числа:\n"))
b = int(input())
if a > b:
    print("Наибольшее число a =", a)
elif b > a:
    print(f"Наибольшее число b =", b)
else:
    print(f"Оба числа равны", b)
```